# Configuring Postfix with other SMTP provider

Tags: email, postfix, sendgrid

I want to use SendGrid as my email sending service, but want to also use Postfix's internal queue mechanism to manage the emails sent through Sendgrid.

So basically what I want to do is to configure Postfix to send emails through Sendgrid's SMTP, and I will configure my app to send the emails using the local Postfix.

My question is, how can I configure Postfix to use an external SMTP? Looked [here](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html) but didn't see anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is detailed in http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#relayhost

Comment: Thanks. I got about the same thing at http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/postfix/ and I just needed to copy paste it and it worked. It's basically the same thing you said, so I'm going to accept your answer in about 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got things figured out, but for future reference to anyone who's looking:

**1) Edit your Postfix configuration file**

Open up your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` config file and edit it to have the following values:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:yourSendgridUsername:yourSendgridPassword 
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous 
smtp_tls_security_level = may
start_tls = yes
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
```

**2) Restart your postfix server**

Run the following command in your terminal

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

**3) Start sending**

You're all set, go ahead and start sending with your SendGrid account!

---

If you run into any issues, you can always ask our [24/7 support team](http://support.sendgrid.com) or tweet at [@SendGrid](http://twitter.com/SendGrid).

Comment: Exactly what I did. Very straight-forward :) Thanks!

Comment: If submission to your service is always encrypted, you should use **smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt**. *start_tls* is not a postfix configuration setting; remove it.