# postfix warning - unused parameter: start_tls= yes

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-12.04, tls

I am a front-end developer and am managing my own linux server for the first time. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and have an SSL certificate. Using Google apps mail as my mailserver, and SendGrid to send out emails from my application.

To integrate SendGrid into postfix, SendGrid docs state to add the code below to /etc/postfix/main.cf and restart the server:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:yourSendGridUsername:yourSendGridPassword 
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous 
smtp_tls_security_level = may
start_tls = yes
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
```

I've made these updates. Once the server restarts, I am getting the error messages below. Each message repeats 8-10 times or so:

```
* Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: start_tls=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: start_tls=yes

/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: start_tls=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: start_tls=yes
```

**Any idea what's causing these messages and how to fix them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is not a duplicate of it, it appears that an existing question RE: SendGrid settings contains the solution. Refer to @adaptr's comment.

[Configuring Postfix with other SMTP provider](https://serverfault.com/questions/425951/configuring-postfix-with-other-smtp-provider)

Comment: Thank you for this. I've accepted and upvoted your answer. It's a good research starting point for me, and it resolved the issue. For anyone googling this issue, the comment Andrew B refers to is here - http://serverfault.com/questions/425951/configuring-postfix-with-other-smtp-provider#comment456014_426000

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know how to find those direct comment links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As found in [the linked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/425951/configuring-postfix-with-other-smtp-provider), `start_tls = yes` isn't valid.  Use this instead:

```
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```